# Report break page or repeat header if it wont fit on page.

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I am making a report with VS 2012 and I need to have it either break page or just copy the header of the group it is in if it cant fit the page. I have tried messing with the advanced row group settings (Keep Together, Repeat on new page, Keep with group, etc) but nothing has worked. I think it might need an expression because of this but I have no idea where to start.